# Can we wrap text in Excel without affecting heights of other cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Question**: Can we wrap text in Excel without affecting other cells. As a sample example, can we re-adjust the heights of the `Ce1l11 and Cell12` to their original heights while still keep the Cell13 with wrapped text and without changing the font size of `Cell13`? I would like the heights of Cell11 and Cell12 to be the same as of the height of second row shown below. I'm using latest version of `Excel-2021`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you manually set the row height prior to typing in the cell it should maintain the same height and or width if you set width as well.
If you want to prevent others from changing the height/width you need to protect the sheet, if you want to still be able to edit the text you will need to ensure the cells are not locked in the protection tab of the format cells pop-up prior to protecting the worksheet.

HTH
Justin